# Create EKS cluster via EKSCTL with a specific role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

When I create my eks cluster,via eksctl, I want to assingn a specifc role that I created for it, but all the time he asks permission for create a new role for EKS.
Why ?
How can I create my eks cluster via eksctl with a specific role?

Answer (score 0):

You could create previously an IAM role manually or using eksctl https://eksctl.io/usage/iamserviceaccounts/

Then you will have to specify the ARN of that role on the eksctl template https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/